# Find hash ("#") in XRegExp with comments

Tags: javascript, regex, xregexp

If you use the 'x' flag of XRegExp, it is unclear how to add the literal '#' to the search.

[The documentation](http://xregexp.com/syntax/) does not appear to yield any illumination.

For example:

```
> XRegExp("the # hey",'x').toString()
'/the(?:)/'
```

This is as expected - everything after '#' is a comment and ignored.

The apparent solution, not ignoring the `#` and following contents on that line, would usually be (based on my limited experience) leading with an escape modifier, eg `\\`:

```
> XRegExp("the \# hey",'x').toString()
'/the(?:)/'
```

or

```
> XRegExp("the \\# hey",'x').toString()
'/the(?:)\\#(?:)hey/'
```

Unfortunately neither works as expected, the prior for obvious reasons, and the latter yields:

```
> XRegExp("the \\# hey",'x').xtest("the # hey")
false
```

or even in the more pernicious case that we must modify input data:

```
> XRegExp("the \\# hey",'x').xtest("the \\# hey")
false
```

The alternative canonical escaping would be using a double-hash (`##`), but that does not work either:

```
> XRegExp("the ## hey",'x').toString()
'/the(?:)/'
```

So the question becomes, how can one add a `#` literal to an XRegExp expression that uses the 'x' flag? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer and please note that my tests above would not work because the spaces should be replaced by `\\s+`.

The answer seems to be to use `[#]` e.g.

```
> XRegExp("the\\s+[#]\\s+hey",'x').xtest("the # hey")
true
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for flag `x` is at http://xregexp.com/flags/#extended.

One of the effects of `x` is that whitespace in your regex pattern is ignored. I see you've discovered that the literal spaces in your regex can be replaced with `\s` (`\\s` when embedded in a string literal due to string escaping rules). But note that that's changing your pattern from matching just a space char to matching any whitespace char. Alternatively you could just escape the spaces: `XRegExp('the\\ \\# \\ hey', 'x')`. Or you could use `[ ]` in the same way you used `[#]`. Or you could do something like `XRegExp('the' + XRegExp.escape(' # ') + 'hey', 'x')`. Or just not use the `x` flag if you have literal whitespace and `#` chars in your pattern.